# Store and retrieve ArrayList of custom serializable class from bundle

Tags: android, serialization, arraylist, bundle, classcastexception

I know there are many questions on storing `ArrayList`s in `Bundle`s here on stackoverflow, but even after reading many of them and the documentation, I do not understand the problem I describe below. I am not so much asking for help with solving this particular programming issue, because I have a "solution", but rather want to understand why I get the error and why my "solution" works.

The standard `PointF` class is (unfortunately) not serializable, which is why I extend that class and (hopefully correctly) implement the code for the serialization of `pointF`s as follows:

```
class PointFSerializable extends PointF implements Serializable
{
    public PointFSerializable(PointF pointF) {
        super(pointF.x, pointF.y);
    }
    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException {
        out.writeFloat(x);
        out.writeFloat(y);
    }
    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        float x = in.readFloat();
        float y = in.readFloat();
        set(x,y);
    }
    private void readObjectNoData() throws ObjectStreamException {
        set(0f,0f);        
    }
}
```

Now I have a nested `ArrayList` of such `PointFSerializable` objects, which is `serializable` because `ArrayList` and `PointFSerializable` are serializable, and which I can hence put into a `Bundle bundle` as follows:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<PointFSerializable>> drawingSerializable = new 
ArrayList<ArrayList<PointFSerializable>>();
  //populate the nested ArrayList
for([...]) {
  ArrayList<PointFSerializable> strokeSerializable = new ArrayList<PointFSerializable>();
  for([...]) {
    strokeSerializable.add(new PointFSerializable(...));
  }
  drawingSerializable.add(strokeSerializable);
}
  //Put it into the Bundle
bundle.putSerializable("Drawing", drawingSerializable);
```

In a different function I later retrieve the nested `ArrayList` from the `Bundle bundle` via `getSerializable()` and a cast as follows:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<PointFSerializable>> drawingSerializable = (ArrayList<ArrayList<PointFSerializable>>)bundle.getSerializable("Drawing");
```

Up to here everything works as expected, but now I want to loop over the `drawingSerializable`:

```
for(ArrayList<PointFSerializable> strokeSerializable : drawingSerializable) {
  for(PointFSerializable pointFSerializable : strokeSerializable) { //<--
    [...]
  }
}
```

In the line marked with the `<--` I get a

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.PointF cannot be cast to com.cgogolin.myapp.PointFSerializable
```

which is what I don't understand.

I would have expected this error is `strokeSerializable` were of tpye `ArrayList<PointF>`, but, evidently it should not be, because I defined it to be of type `ArrayList<PointFSerializable>` and if it were not of that type then I would have expected to already get an error in the outer for loop.

Now, in the body of the inner for loop I anyway want to cast the `pointFSerializable` to `PointF`. I can hence replace the problematic line by

```
  for(PointF pointF : strokeSerializable) {
```

and then everything works as it should. But why?

Why, from `bundle.getSerializable("Drawing");`, do I apparently getting back something that I can treat like an `ArrayList<ArrayList<PointF>>`  (which is not even a serializable object!) but not like an `ArrayList<ArrayList<PointFSerializable>>`, even though I put an object of the latter type into the Bundle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PointF is parcelable, which means you can put the standard PointF into a bundle. If a class is both serializable and parcelable, Android will defer to write and read to a parcel. What is happening is since you are not overriding the parceling method, Android parcels your object as a standard PointF. If you need the ability to serialize your class outside of that, make sure to override the methods required in the [Parcelable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) interface.

Comment: Yes, I know that the standard `PointF` is `parcelable` and that therefore I can put individual `PointF`s into a Bundle. But I have an `ArrayList`, which is not `parcelable` but `serializable`, of `PointF`s  and hence don't  see how that could help. I explicitly put my `ArrayList` into the `Bundle` via `putSerializable()`, so I don't see how the `parcelable` propoerty of `PointF` could interfere with what I am doing.

Comment: I know it's a bit weird, but there is really no difference between each of the put methods in a bundle other than some object wrapping. If you look at how both `putSerializable()` and `getSerializable()` in the `BaseBundle` class work they first calls `unparcel()`. That call to `unparcel()`, since your object extends parcelable, will use the methods in the parcelable interface to construct the object as Bundles prefer to use parceling over serialization.

Comment: Wow, this is indeed a very "unexpected" behavior. I guess, in the future I will more often look into the source rather than the documentation when I encounter such issues. Thank you very much!